# Dividing long sentence to several lines in table

Tags: tables, line-breaking

I have a sentence in a table that is too long and makes my table go out of the page. How can I make the sentence divide into several lines so it doesn't ruin the layout of the table?

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
\caption{}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\hline
Material & Production & Description & Reference \\
\hline
 & a bene placito a bene placito a bene placito a bene placito &  & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use p{<with>} for the column that has the long sentence. Width may be in cm, pt or another width that is valid for LaTeX.

Answer (score 2):

Use `p{<width>}` for the column that has the long sentence. The width may be in cm, pt or another width that is valid for LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htb]
\caption{}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lp{4cm}ll}
\hline
Material & Production & Description & Reference \\
\hline
 & a bene placito a bene placito a bene placito a bene placito &  & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

To have a nicer tabular, I suggest loading the `array` and `booktabs` packages, and use `\toprule`, `midrule` and `bottomrule` instead of `\hline`.

`p{}`-columns are set justified by default, so you may also consider to set the wide column ragged right. Standard LaTeX `\raggedright` does not hyphenate word, so if your text is very ragged, you need hyphenation in the ragged column. Load the package [ragged2e](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) in the preamble and use the command `\RaggedRight` instead of `\raggedright`. In your example, you will no see any difference, but try a narrow column with some long words. Here is a modified MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e,array,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htb]
\caption{}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l>{\RaggedRight}p{4cm}ll}
\toprule
Material & Production & Description & Reference \\
\midrule
 & a bene placito a bene placito a bene placito a bene placito &  & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]